# How to set access level as "Public" for all files uploading to an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created an S3 bucket and also an API through the AWS API Gateway to upload images to the bucket. **The problem is, when I upload an image, to view that image I need to update the Access control list (ACL) to Public for each image separately.** Even though I set everything to the public in the bucket permissions, still I have to update the ACL in each image to access them. How can I set the access level to "Public" for the whole bucket once?

This is my bucket permissions:

Access: **Public**

Block all public access: **Off**

Bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1647249671911",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1647249649218",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname"
        }
    ]
}
```

Access control list (ACL):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current policy is **highly insecure** and allows anyone to do pretty much anything with your bucket, including changing it policy or deleting it.
The [correct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2) bucket policy for public, **read-only** access is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked! So, if you set everything to the public, AWS doesn't allow all the objects to get applied at once right?

Comment: @DavidJohns Not sure what you mean. But with the above policy, all objects are publicly readable.